# insert NA into a time series object in r

Tags: r, time-series, missing-data, na

i want to sum the months for all the years in a time series that looks like

```
         Jan Feb Mar Apr Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2006              4   4   3    4   4   5   5   3  3
2007      3   3   2   2   4    3   3   2   2   5  5
2008      3   3   3   2   2    4   4   3
```

by using 
          window(the time series object,start=c(2006,3),end=c(2008,3),frequency=1)
  this line gives you a new ts object with just march of 2006-2007. However this does not work when the month does not have any values in it, is there any way to replace the gaps with NA? I have seen questions like this before but the dont answer i think for a ts object.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

```
the_time_series_object <- ts(1:31, frequency = 12, start = c(2006, 3))
```

then:

```
window(the time series object, start = c(2006,3), end = c(2008,3), frequency = 12)
```

Your frequency should be 12 instead of 1. There's no NA problem it's just that one variable that you have wrong

Comment: the thing is i choose the frequency of 1 so that i only get a specific month for all the range of years so i can add for example all of aprils from 2006 2007 2008 and get an average of just aprils. I found my answer though by using require(zoo)
require(chron))
y <- zoo(seas)
yrt2 <- range(msub$time)
y0 <- zoo(,seq(from = yrt2[1], to = yrt2[2], by = "month"))
merge(y2, y0) this merge fills in the times that dont overlap with NAs

Comment: In that case you could just omit the end value like this: window(the time series object, start = c(2006,3), frequency = 1)